# Limit echo string number

Tags: php

I'm currently working on retrieving data from coinmarketcap API and I would like to limit the strings to 5. I retrieve the data and then multiply the value `*1.07` and the result to `MXN`, but the string is long, like `25.65675734343`, I want to limit that string, this is my echo:

```
echo $xrpprice*$rate*$fxrates['rates']['MXN'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `round`:

```
$result = $xrpprice*$rate*$fxrates['rates']['MXN'];
echo round($result,2);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks

Comment: @AlfredoSanroman You're welcome, if this solved your issue, please click the 'checkmark' to accept answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to control how many decimal places. Assuming you don't want to limit the whole number to just five characters.

```
echo number_format($numberToFormat, $numberOfDecimalPlaces);
```

Please better explain your question. Also, what have you tried?